# Set Border.Brush property according to Mouse State and Position

Tags: c#, wpf, border, mouse, brush

I'm trying to change my UserControl's Border.BorderBrush property depending on if the Mouse enters, leaves, or is down on my UserControl. I've tried doing it explicitly in the code behind, but anytime the Border.BorderBrush property is changed, the border disappears.

I went down a string of possible solutions with no avail. As of my current codebase I'm attempting to use a Style and Triggers to manage it for me. My issue there is that there is no property for IsMouseDown unless you're dealing with a Button (at least that's what I've gathered from reading), so I defined a property for that.

Just when I think it's going to work, the border can't find my Style defined in UserControl.Resources.

I've exhausted everything I know to do, any help would be extremely appreciated.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OSK.Resources.Themes.Default.Key"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OSK.Resources.Themes.Default"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            x:Name="OSKuwuDefaultKey"
            d:DesignHeight="48" d:DesignWidth="48">
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style x:Name="KeyStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Path=BrushHover, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Path=BrushNormal, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="local:Key.IsMouseDown" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Path=BrushDown, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
<Border x:Name="key" Background="Transparent" Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=OSKuwuDefaultKey}" Height="{Binding Path=Height, ElementName=OSKuwuDefaultKey}" BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=OSKuwuDefaultKey}" CornerRadius="{Binding Path=CornerRadius, ElementName=OSKuwuDefaultKey}" BorderThickness="{Binding Path=OutlineThickness, ElementName=OSKuwuDefaultKey}" MouseEnter="Key_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Key_MouseLeave" MouseDown="Key_MouseDown" MouseUp="Key_MouseUp">
    <Canvas>
        <Label Content="{Binding SuperText, ElementName=OSKuwuDefaultKey}" Canvas.Top="6" Canvas.Left="8" />
        <Label Content="{Binding SubText, ElementName=OSKuwuDefaultKey}" Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Right="4" />
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Code-Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace OSK.Resources.Themes.Default
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Key.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Key : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SuperTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SuperText", typeof(string), typeof(Key), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
        public string SuperText
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(SuperTextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SuperTextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SubTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SubText", typeof(string), typeof(Key), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
        public string SubText
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(SubTextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SubTextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushNormalProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BrushNormal", typeof(Brush), typeof(Key), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.LightSlateGray));
        public Brush BrushNormal
        {
            get
            {
                return (Brush)GetValue(BrushNormalProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(BrushNormalProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushHoverProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BrushHover", typeof(Brush), typeof(Key), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.LightSteelBlue));
        public Brush BrushHover
        {
            get
            {
                return (Brush)GetValue(BrushHoverProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(BrushHoverProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushDownProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BrushDown", typeof(Brush), typeof(Key), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.SlateGray));
        public Brush BrushDown
        {
            get
            {
                return (Brush)GetValue(BrushDownProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(BrushDownProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(int), typeof(Key), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(4, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
        public int CornerRadius
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OutlineThickness", typeof(Thickness), typeof(Key), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(1), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
        public Thickness OutlineThickness
        {
            get
            {
                return (Thickness)GetValue(OutlineThicknessProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(OutlineThicknessProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty IsMouseDownProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsMouseDown", typeof(bool), typeof(Key), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool)));
        public bool IsMouseDown
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(IsMouseDownProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IsMouseDownProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public Key()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Key_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //this.SetValue(Key.BorderBrushProperty, BrushNormal);
            //Console.WriteLine(GetValue(Key.BorderBrushProperty));
        }

        private void Key_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //this.SetValue(Key.BorderBrushProperty, BrushHover);
        }

        private void Key_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //this.SetValue(Key.BorderBrushProperty, BrushDown);
            this.SetValue(Key.IsMouseDownProperty, true);
        }

        private void Key_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetValue(Key.IsMouseDownProperty, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of declaring the Style as a resource, you could assign it directly: `<UserControl.Style><Style ...>...</Style></UserControl.Style>`. The Bindings in the Setters are missing an appropriate source object, e.g. `{Binding Path=BrushHover, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`

Comment: @Clemens I did try UserControl.Style as well actually, forgot to note that. I get an error saying `'Key' TargetType does not match type of element 'UserControl'.` So I tried changing it to `<local:Key.Style>` but then I get `The member "Style" is not recognized or is not accessible.`

Comment: @Clemens The reason I need TargetType Key is because I need to access my `Key.IsMouseDown` property.

Comment: Your dependency property declarations are incomplete. Please take a look at this, especially *Implementing the "Wrapper"*: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties

Comment: @Clemens updated, same as before.

Comment: @Clemens I removed the Border.BorderBrush binding to test some things, forgot to put it back. It's working, but not as intended. It updates hover but only when I'm over the Border, or either of the two Labels, not in between.

Comment: Set Background to Transparent, otherwise the Border element won't get mouse input in the areas that aren't occupied by child elements.

Comment: @GeoDoX Given that behavior, it sounds like the Border Background is transparent, and the mouse handling is not being triggered unless on the Border or Label (so mouse hover inside the border gets missed). As a temporary fix, try setting the Border Background to a solid color, so that it picks up the mouseover events.

Comment: Also don't use a Canvas for stacked layout of Labels and similar elements. Use a StackPanel instead, and set the Margin property of the Labels. And for text-only display, TextBlock is less heavy than Label.

Comment: @codechinchilla "*a solid color*" should be the usual `Background="Transparent"`, which is different from the default `null` Background.

Comment: @Clemens Setting the Background to Transparent worked like a charm. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The original post has the final working code.

And the layout should look like this, without explicitly setting the size of the Border:

```
<Border x:Name="key" Background="Transparent" 
    BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=OSKuwuDefaultKey}"
    CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, ElementName=OSKuwuDefaultKey}" 
    BorderThickness="{Binding OutlineThickness, ElementName=OSKuwuDefaultKey}"
    MouseEnter="Key_MouseEnter"
    MouseLeave="Key_MouseLeave"
    MouseDown="Key_MouseDown"
    MouseUp="Key_MouseUp">

    <Canvas>
        ...
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```